# how to change color of IconButton on listView load based on a conditon, before onPress flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, colors, icons

I have a `ListView` of posts and have like `IconButton` in every row or post. Now user can like any post. I need to check if user liked a post and that post's like `IconButton` will be blue. The post that user not liked, `IconButton` color will be grey. I need to check it when the list of post is loading.

List:

```dart
    children: <Widget> [
        Row(
           children: <Widget>[
           new IconButton(
           icon: new Icon(Icons.thumb_up),

           // documentId = list[index].id;
           // want to get documentId in this way from here and pass this documentId to the method like  checkPostLikedOrNot(documentId); 
           //  checkFeedLikedOrNot(documentId ); 
           // want to call this method here and check the conditon    
           
          color:(isPressed) ? Color(0xff007397) : Color(0xff9A9A9A),
           onPressed: (){
             print(widget.userId); // userId
             documentId = list[index].id;
             _counter = list[index].data()["like_count"];
             _incrementCounter(); // updating table with userId in this method
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
```

Check method:

```dart
    checkFeedLikedOrNot(documentId) async{
      DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('post').doc(documentId);
      DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = await docRef.get();
      List likedUser = docSnapshot.data()['liked_user_id'];
      if(likedUser.contains(widget.userId) == true){
         print('user already exist=='+ widget.userId);
         //color will be blue
      }else{
         //color will be grey
    }
  }
```

Building `ListView`

```
return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  primary: false,
                  itemCount: list.length,
                  itemBuilder:(context, index)  {
                    print(index);
                    return Card(
                      elevation: 5,
                      shape: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlue, width: 5)),
                        child: Column(
                            children: <Widget> [
                              ListTile(
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note about improving security: your API should have a method to check if user liked a post by `userId` and `postId` (or get all liked posts' ids for given `userId` with pagination). It's not a good way to get all users who liked a post.

You can use [`FutureBuilder`](https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9).

The check method should return `Future<bool>`

```dart
   Future<bool> checkFeedLikedOrNot(documentId) async {
      DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('post').doc(documentId);
      DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = await docRef.get();
      List likedUser = docSnapshot.data()['liked_user_id'];
      return likedUser.contains(widget.userId);
  }
```

Then you can use `FutureBuilder` to get `Icon`

```dart
  Widget getIcon(documentId) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        Color color = Colors.grey; // set proper default color
        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            snapshot.hasData != null) {
          color = Colors.blue; // set proper "liked" color
        }
        return Icon(
            Icons.thumb_up,
            color: color,
          );
      },
      future: checkFeedLikedOrNot(documentId),
    );
  }
```

And use this method in `IconButton`

```dart
new IconButton(
           icon: getIcon(list[index].id),

           // documentId = list[index].id;
           // want to get documentId in this way from here and pass this documentId to the method like  checkPostLikedOrNot(documentId); 
           // checkFeedLikedOrNot(documentId ); 
           // want to call this method here and check the conditon    
           
          color:(isPressed) ? Color(0xff007397) : Color(0xff9A9A9A),
           onPressed: (){
             print(widget.userId); // userId
             documentId = list[index].id;
             _counter = list[index].data()["like_count"];
             _incrementCounter(); // updating table with userId in this method
              },
            ),
```

Comment: when trying to add your code in IconButton it is giving  error " The await expression can only be used in an async function." @ Owczar

Comment: @user12371061, it's because the function where you create your list is not async. It should look like my `checkFeedLikedOrNot` function (with the `Future` (probably `Future<Widget>`) return type and the `async` keyword)

Comment: after adding async getting error :   " The argument type 'Future<Card> Function(BuildContext, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, int)'. "

Comment: @user12371061, I analyzed deeper your question and improve my answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but still facing issue  that snapshot returns null.

Comment: `snapshot` is null when the code waits for response from `checkFeedLikedOrNot`. I've edited `getIcon` method to handle that.

Comment: thanks for your update but facing issue. Please help me as you are alreay trying to help me a lot but i am not able to solve it.  I have posted full code to another post in this link :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64185169/how-to-change-color-of-iconbutton-listview-onload-flutter